# JavaScript solution for anagram of a palindrome

Tags: javascript

I was asked to implement the same question as this in an interview recently:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447222/anagram-of-a-palindrome

I could not provide an answer but am interested to know the JavaScript solution.

Comment: This is nothing more than a "give me the code" question.  The answer is in the post that you linked.

Comment: What exactly is it that you are having problems with or you are trying to understand?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Anagram of a palindrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447222/anagram-of-a-palindrome)

Comment: Exact duplicate, just with demand to write code in some language for fully explained algorithm. I'd still prefer to close as duplicate, so it'd redirect to real answer.

Answer (score 3):

That should be working..But I have tested it only with few inputs:) At least the theory behind it should be OK..

```
String.prototype.count=function(char) { 
    return this.split(char).length-1;
}

function isAnagramOfPalyndrom(string){
    string.replace(" ", "");  
    var even = string.length % 2 == 0;
    var flag = false;


    for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){

    if(string.count(string.charAt(i)) % 2 != 0){
       if(even) return false;
       else{
        if(flag) return false;
        flag = true;
       }
    }



}
return true;


}
```

Comment: not working for aaabbbb

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, if you have an even number of every letter except 1, it's an anagram of a palindrome.

See: "Kayak" k:2, a:2, y:1
See: "SAAS" s:2, a:2

Comment: i.e. "Kayak" k: 2, a: 2, y: 1

Comment: That example is useful. You should edit it into your answer, not post it as a comment.

Comment: Palindromes don't have to have a single "pivot" letter, do they?

Comment: That's what is also said in the answers to the other question (similarly). I don't see a point in repeating it here. The answer given there is generic enough, the problem seems to be that the OP does not know JavaScript well enough.

Comment: @Pointy correct, you can have an anagram of a palindrome where ALL letters occur an even number of times. However, you must also account for the pivot case.

Comment: Also, LOL. I didn't even notice that the answer was already listed because I didn't follow that link. You should really read more carefully OP, people get real snooty about that around here ;) (but in reality the people who are most helpful here are also very, very busy people, so it is considerate to do as much research beforehand as you can)